# pandas filter value counts with more than one answer

Tags: pandas

Say I have this dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ('max', 'park', True),
    ('max', 'home', False),
    ('max', 'somewhere', True),
    ('spot', 'home', False),
    ('spot', 'park', False),
    ('bell', 'home', True),
    ('bell', 'park', True),
], columns='name,location,seen'.split(','))
df
```

[image: df]

How do I find everyone who has been seen in one place, but not another? An alternative way to phrase this question is how do I filter a MultiIndex series with more than one value in a given index.

```py
df.groupby('name').seen.value_counts()
```

```
name  seen 
bell  True     2
max   True     2
      False    1
spot  False    2
Name: seen, dtype: int64
```

I want to filter to see just max in this case. E.g. I would like this:

[image]

Comment: can you show us your intended output ?

Comment: by not another, do you mean they have at least one `False` value which is unique? in my head, Bell would also be included in your list but isn't because she has no false value?

Comment: You're right, Datanovice, a poor example/phrasing on my part to get what I wanted. An answer I wanted did come out of it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: @unutbu provides two elegant solutions in the comments:

```
# Option 1: groupby.transform
df.loc[df.groupby(['name'])['seen'].transform('nunique') > 1]

# Option 2: groupby.filter
df.groupby(['name']).filter(lambda x: x['seen'].nunique() > 1)
```

[Old answer follows]

Here's one way that uses a boolean mask to select names with two unique `seen` values:

```
mask = df.groupby('name').seen.nunique().eq(2)
names = mask[mask].index
df[df['name'].isin(names)]

  name   location   seen
0  max       park   True
1  max       home  False
2  max  somewhere   True
```

Comment: A riff on the same idea: `df.loc[df.groupby(['name'])['seen'].transform('nunique') > 1]`

Comment: Also possible: `df.groupby(['name']).filter(lambda x: x['seen'].nunique() > 1)`.

Comment: @unutbu, both those answers are cooler than mine! I'll edit them into the body of my answer.